# Bad encode cyrillic symbols when use win_update module of ansible

Tags: windows, ansible, cyrillic, windows-update

Use win_update module of ansible

Playbook:

```
- name: Update
  tasks:
  - name: Check updates
    register: result
    win_updates:
      state: searched
  - debug: var=result
  hosts: windows
```

Hosts:

```
all:
  children:
    windows:
      hosts:
        somehost:
```

Group_vars:

```
ansible_user: someuser
ansible_password: somepassword
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_port: 5986
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

in debug get results:

```
ok: [somehost] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": false, 
        "filtered_updates": {}, 
        "found_update_count": 2, 
        "installed_update_count": 0, 
        "reboot_required": false, 
        "updates": {
            "8fde14d1-2fd6-4705-b2ab-b2aaf1aa7a05": {
                "id": "8fde14d1-2fd6-4705-b2ab-b2aaf1aa7a05", 
                "installed": false, 
                "kb": [
                    "4054518"
                ], 
                "title": "��������� ����� ��ࠢ����� ����⢠ ��⥬� ������᭮�� ��� ��⥬ Windows 7 �� ���� �����஢ x64 (KB4054518), 12 2017 �."
            }, 
            "bc3e1d56-c863-467e-a13d-77460eff0dcc": {
                "id": "bc3e1d56-c863-467e-a13d-77460eff0dcc", 
                "installed": false, 
                "kb": [
                    "890830"
                ], 
                "title": "�।�⢮ 㤠����� �।������ �ணࠬ� ��� ������� x64: ���� 2018 �. (KB890830)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where should I make changes of code for normal windows update title names?
win_update powershell script or winrm or somewhere else

**update:**
Unfortunately when I use stable version of ansible (2.4.3.0), get error:

```
ansible win10.dev -i hosts -m win_updates -a 'state=searched'
win10.dev | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "module_stderr": "An error occurred while creating the pipeline.\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException\r\n \r\nTimed out waiting for scheduled task to start\r\nAt line:334 char:9\r\n+         Throw \"Timed out waiting for scheduled task to start\"\r\n+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Timed out waiti...d task to start:String) [], RuntimeException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Timed out waiting for scheduled task to start\r\n \r\n\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
    "rc": 1
}
```

In this thread(https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/25298) I did not found decision, so I have to use @devel branch of ansible repository.

Answer (score 0):

Everything should work out of the box. It's `UTF-8`. Ensure that your current shell is UTF-enabled.

Ansible box:

```
$ locale
LANG="ru_RU.UTF-8"
...
$ ansible --version
ansible 2.4.2.0
...
$ ansible winsrv -m win_updates -a 'state=searched'
...
   "title": "Накопительное обновление для Windows Server 2016 для систем на базе процессоров x64, 2018 03 (KB4088787)"
...
   "title": "Обновление для Windows Server 2016 для систем на базе процессоров x64 (KB4049065), 11.2017"
...
```

Windows box:

```
PS> [cultureinfo]::InstalledUICulture

LCID         Name         DisplayName
----         ----         -----------
1049         ru-RU        Русский (Россия)
```

Comment: In my update I described error with stable version, so I use @devel branch. I have no success still in spite of all of your recommendations have been tested

Comment: Dump the result into file with `copy` and `content: "{{result}}"` and inspect if its indeed UTF-8 with text editor. If that is the case, this is definitely a shell/terminal issue; otherwise – i'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

**Decision**

Powershell has default output encoding settings. So all my windows hosts has

```
>[Console]::OutputEncoding

IsSingleByte      : True
BodyName          : cp866
EncodingName      : Кириллица (DOS)
HeaderName        : cp866
WebName           : cp866
WindowsCodePage   : 1251
IsBrowserDisplay  : True
IsBrowserSave     : True
IsMailNewsDisplay : False
IsMailNewsSave    : False
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalEncoderBestFitFallback
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.InternalDecoderBestFitFallback
IsReadOnly        : True
CodePage          : 866
```

2 ways:

1. Set default powershell output encoding at host with windows
2. In ansible sources in file ansible/modules/windows/win_updates.ps1 add line of code:

   [Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding("utf-8")